# Log when my bot joins a new server & leaves to a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to have it so when my bot is added/removed from servers, it logs it to a text file! How can I do this? This is the code I have right now:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild.
    console.log(`New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
});

client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    // this event triggers when the bot is removed from a guild.
    console.log(`I have been removed from: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id})`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to help!

You can use the built-in Node.JS module called FS. FS stands for file system, which allows you to write, delete, append, etc. to files on your system.

Here's an example:

```
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild.
    console.log(`New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
    const fs = require('fs');

    fs.appendFile('./file.txt', `Added to Guild: ${guild.name} Id: ${guild.id} Member Count: ${guild.memberCount}`, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    // this event triggers when the bot is removed from a guild.
    console.log(`I have been removed from: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id})`);
    const fs = require('fs');

    fs.appendFile('./file.txt', `Removed from Guild: ${guild.name} Id: ${guild.id}`, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

If this doesn't work let me know!

Good luck, have fun, and have a nice day!

Comment: is this possible that we can also add the invite link of the servers bot joined?